# Python script only writes partial results to file

Tags: python, file-io, proxy, python-requests

I have a little python script that I wrote to populate my proxychains.conf file with valid public proxies. For each request, 10 proxies are retrieved and added to proxychains.conf, and this is done 3 times so that a total of 30 proxies are added.

When I was writing the script and having results return to stdout everything worked as expected = 30 proxies were retrieved and returned. However when I added the file operations part of the script only 10 proxies are written to the file. I'm still learning Python and I've tried to rearrange some things but it's not working out. I can't figure out if :

1. my counter is in the wrong place?
2. my file operations are in the wrong place?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import sys,os

proxy_file = '/etc/proxychains.conf'
base_url = 'http://proxy.tekbreak.com/10/json'
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20'}

def fetchprox():
    pf = open(proxy_file, 'r')
    lines = pf.readlines()
    pf.close()
    with open (proxy_file, 'w') as f:
        del lines[69:]
        f.writelines([item for item in lines[:-1]])
        r = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
        n = 0
        while n < 10:
            ip = r.json()[n]['ip']
            port = r.json()[n]['port']
            p_type = r.json()[n]['type']

         #output to proxychains.conf
            f.writelines(str(p_type + " " + ip + " " + port + "\n"))
            n += 1    

for i in range(0,3):  
    fetchprox()
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**
I found a solution based off of Giordano's answer, however I believe it could be implemented better. It seems redundant to have to access this file 3 times to just to write some data. So here is the portion of the script that was changed:

```
<--snip->
pf = open(proxy_file, 'r')
lines = pf.readlines()
pf.close()

f = open (proxy_file, 'w')
del lines[69:]
f.writelines([item for item in lines[:-2]])
f.close()

def fetchprox():
    with open (proxy_file, 'a') as f:
        r = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
        n = 0
        while n < 10:
<--snip-->
```

so is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: try to change with open (proxy_file, 'w') as f: in with open (proxy_file, 'a') as f:. Probably you are overwrite the file each time

Comment: As I see, you read your list of proxies from `proxy_file` and write the result to the *same* file. You overwrite it, so after the first iteration only 10 lines are left. No matter how many times you run the loop, it would always be 10 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is correct, but as I mentioned in a comment, you overwrite your file each loop. 
More in detail, the wrong line is the following:

```
with open (proxy_file, 'w') as f:
```

With `w`, you write a file, but if it is not empty, you overwrite the content. 
To fix it you can use `append` mode in this way:

```
with open (proxy_file, 'a') as f:
```

**append** does not overwrite the content of the file but adds new lines.

**Answer after edit**

First of all you can use `with` to open a file, and so i've removed also .close() because `with` handle closure automatically.
I also changed the `while` loop with a `for` loop in this way:

```
lines = None
with open(proxy_file, 'r') as pf:
    lines = pf.readlines()

with open (proxy_file, 'w') as f:
    del lines[69:]
    f.writelines([item for item in lines[:-2]])

def fetchprox():
    with open (proxy_file, 'a') as f:
        data = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers).json()
        for element in data:
            ip = element['ip']
            port = element['port']
            p_type = element['type']

            #output to proxychains.conf
            f.writelines(str(p_type + " " + ip + " " + port + "\n"))

for i in range(0,3): 
    fetchprox()
```

**Second edit**

If you want remove one access to the file, you can use `r+` mode in this way:

```
lines = None
with open(proxy_file, 'r+') as pf:
    lines = pf.readlines()
    del lines[69:]
    pf.writelines([item for item in lines[:-2]])
...
```

With `r+` you can read and write, opening one time the file.

Comment: Hi Giordano thanks for the suggestion. When I implemented `'a'` the script actually rewrote the entire contents of proxychains.conf and then only 10 proxy servers. I was able to find a solution which i will add as an edit to th original question because I do believe there is a better solution.

Comment: Giordano - your edit works perfectly. I'm still a little confused when to use `f = open(file, 'r')` and `with open (file, 'r') as f`, and thanks for the tip about using the '+' to open the file in read/write. Additionally using a `for` statement instead of a `while` loop. I wasn't sure how to grab every instance of **ip** from the json file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help you! to understand better when to use "open" and when to use "with", please read the Python documentation. Please if your problems are fixed, mark the answer as accepted in order to help also other users with the same problem. Best regards